# How to store all the values retrieved from database into string variables or array

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am retrieving the values of the column named `"Product Name"` from the table `ProductItems`.

Using the `For[...]Loop`, I am getting the column values for each row.

During the first loop, value of `s1` is **pen**. In the second loop, value of `s1` is **pencil only** and it goes on. In the last loop, the value stored in `s1` is **watercolor only**.

I want  all these values of `ProductName` to be stored in string `s1`. I tried to use `String.Join` method and storing the values in a string array, but it doesnt work.

This is my code:

```
Dim s1 As String = Nothing
Dim s2() As String = Nothing
Dim index As Integer

myConnection.Open()
table = New DataTable
str = "SELECT * FROM ProductItems"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
adapter.Fill(table)
For index = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
    s1 = table.Rows(index)("Product Name").ToString
Next
myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: How do you want all of the strings stored in a single string? Comma separated? Or would you prefer an array?

Comment: So what you're asking is how to join two `Strings` together.  I don't believe that you've never done that before or, in the unlikely case that you haven't, that you could find out how to do it with a simple web search.

Comment: I Want to store the string with Blankspace (" ") as an seperator. I prefer array for storing the values. @Enigmativity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from your question exactly what your desired result is, but you might try something like this as a start:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Main
  Sub Main()
    Dim oProducts As List(Of String)
    Dim aProducts As String()
    Dim sSqlQuery As String
    Dim oTable As DataTable

    sSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ProductItems"
    oTable = New DataTable

    Using oConnection As New OleDbConnection
      Using oCommand As New OleDbCommand(sSqlQuery, oConnection)
        Using oAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(oCommand)
          oConnection.Open()
          oAdapter.Fill(oTable)
        End Using
      End Using
    End Using

    oProducts = New List(Of String)

    For iIndex As Integer = 0 To oTable.Rows.Count - 1
      oProducts.Add(oTable.Rows(iIndex)("Product Name"))
    Next

    aProducts = oProducts.ToArray
  End Sub
End Module
```

`aProducts` is now an array containing all of the Product Names from your table.

Comment: Not related to the question - but can you answer what benefit you get from using `s,o,a` prefixes in variable name. Our team is one of them which using same and I trying to find explanation for them why they should't do this?

Comment: It works.I want these values to be compared with the user input and to calculate the price for the products based on quantity. Thank you so much. @InteXX

Comment: @Fabio — It's known as [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). In this case, the prefix indicates the variable's data type. Personally, I use the convention mostly to delineate the difference between private (in-method) variables and class fields. `oCustomers` is a different collection than `Me.Customers`, for example. HTH

Comment: @SathyaThangaraj — You're welcome; I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Hungarion notation used for describing a type of variable. But you use ´o´ for ´List´, ´DataTable´ and other different types. So I still don't see benefits of this habit. Thanks for answering, I think I know how I can convince my co-workers to not use it anymore

Comment: @Fabio — So, I'm to provide fodder for its demise, eh? ;-) The convention here is my own personal evolution. I use `o` for pretty much every variable that holds a Reference type; the other letters generally indicate Value types. There are edge case exceptions to this, of course, but it's all part of my own convention I've adopted and refined for myself over the years. The one thing that's constant is that I use it only for private, in-method variables. `iCustomers = oCustomers.Count` HTH